# My whm said jsp doesn't work on their economy plan(Shared hosting), take a vps. Why is it so?

Tags: jsp, web, web-applications, hosting, vps

I have a domain and we are trying to deploy a webapp we developed to our hosting server. We got economy plan on web hosting provider. Later found out we don't have much of access as well as our JSP files not working and no access to servlet or apache configurations. The support of hosting site said take a VPS. Am bit new to the software field. But why vps for that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per your question if it is WHM/cpanel this totally depends on the OS and Java Tomcat is enabled in it or not. Note: that the hosting providers usually do not offer this feature in shared hosting environment,

Also if WHM is on Cent OS the Java Tomcat in cpanel can not be used.